# What is the usage of the second argument of Math.floor() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Just tried different second argument of Math.floor(), e.g.

```
Math.floor(1.56, 1)
Math.floor(1.56, -1)
Math.floor(1.56, 0.1)
```

But all of them will get the same result(1). Would anyone knows what is the usage of the second argument of Math.floor() in javascript?

Comment: there is no second parameter ... it does not matter, if exists.

Comment: There is no second argument check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: Read documentation!

Answer (score 0):

When we look into the documentation: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

We can see that there isn't a second parameter. So the code is invalid.